# Float keeps creating unwanted space

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to include a search bar in the header `nav`. I used to do it by using `float` just to let everything vertically centered, but when I do it it gives me a very big space that goes all the way down. I tried to fix it by using `width: 100%` but it gave me another space:

[image]

I also tried `height: 100%` but it didn't work.

How can I remove this unwanted space? I am using Sass.

```css
header {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #4A4C54;
    nav {
        min-height: 12vh;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        width: 90%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
        ul {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            li {
                padding: 0 3rem;
                font-size: 2rem;
                a {
                    color: white;
                }
            }
        }
        h1 {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            a {
                color: white;
                font-size: 3rem;
            }
        }
    }
    input {
        margin: 0;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        bottom: 2.5rem;
        padding: auto 1rem;
        outline: none;
    }
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">تسوق الآن</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">تسوق الآن</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">تسوق الآن</a></li>
            </ul>
            <h1><a href="/">لرم إبسوم</a></h1>
        </nav>
        <input type="search" placeholder="بحث..">
    </header>
```

Comment: Where do you want it to be placed?

Comment: Don’t use `float` for layout purposes - we have flexbox and the CSS grid now (which are far superior in every way!). Floats are meant for images and other large objects surrounded by text, not for page-layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex in the header and the nav. Something like this (you can convert it back to sass using something like [css2sass](https://css2sass.herokuapp.com/)):

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
header {
  background-color: #4A4C54;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
nav a {
  color: white;
}
input {
  margin: 0;
  padding: auto 1rem;
  outline: none;
  width: 120px;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  font-size: 2rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
h1 a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">تسوق الآن</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">تسوق الآن</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">تسوق الآن</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h1><a href="/">لرم إبسوم</a></h1>
    </nav>
    <input type="search" placeholder="بحث..">
</header>
```